# I'm trying to add Apache POI for xlsx which gives me errror after error

Tags: java, apache-poi

Following is my code

```
public static String ReadXLSX(String sheetName, int rowNo, int colNo) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{


File file =new File(ConfigReader.getProperty("filePath"));

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNo);

XSSFCell cell =row.getCell(colNo);

String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
wb.close();

return cellValue;
```

}

I'm using `poi-ooxml-3.15.0` to handle this, but I'm receiving errors one after another:

first it was :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
```

then after getting resolution it became :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
```

and after it's resolution it has become:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/ThemeDocument
```

what could be causing this?

Comment: do you have poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.0 jar in your build path?

Comment: No, is that needed?

Comment: Yes it is, add the dependency and see the error gone.

Comment: I did; but same error.

Comment: Ah, i edited the maven dependency details straight from maven repository, can you try it instead?

Comment: I know that reading the docs isn't very trendy these days, but [what happens if you read the Apache POI docs on the required dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) and add all of those?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure why this is happening, earlier I used to add the ooxml jar and everything used to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, your errors seem to be build path related. What you need at least are the following jars:

- poi-3.15.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.15.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar
- xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

I am not really sure if you also need these:

- commons-codec-1.10.jar
- commons-collections4-4.1.jar
- curvesapi-1.04.jar

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven, just put below dependency and it will pull the rest.

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

Else, just download all the jars below and add to your classpath:

- poi-ooxml 3.15
- poi 3.15
- commons-codec 1.10
- commons-collections4 4.1
- poi-ooxml-schemas 3.15
- xmlbeans 2.6.0
- stax-api 1.0.1
- curvesapi 1.04